# Unable to fetch values from a textarea using DOM

Tags: php, dom

I am using CURL to fetch form and store it in a field

```
..,
$str = curl_exec($ch);
```

The $str HTML has a textarea as follows

```
<td class="fntc">
Description
</td>
<td class="ffc">
<textarea name="descri" rows="6" class="emf" maxlength="128000">fictional.</textarea>
</td>
</tr>
```

Now I am trying to use a dom to fetch this area and was unsuccessful

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($str);

// Get all the textarea field nodes
$inputs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('textarea');
// Iterate over the input fields and save the values we want to an array
foreach ($inputs as $input) {
    $name = $input->getAttribute('name');
    $val = $input->getAttribute('value');
    $field_vals[$name] = $val;
}
```

But i am unable to get the value.Is there anything i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since a `<textarea>` contains text inside the tag, rather than in a `value` attribute, you may access it with `nodeValue`:

```
$val = $input->nodeValue;
```

#### Update

Ok, I've verified this now:

```
$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML("<html><head></head><body><textarea>textarea contents</textarea></body></html>");
$t = $d->getElementsByTagName("textarea");
foreach ($t as $tx) {
  echo $tx->nodeValue;
}

// Prints
// textarea contents
```